# Make Node.js ftp-srv read only without command line

Tags: node.js, ftp

In the ftp-srv Node.js module, there is a command line to set the FTP server as read-only, but how can I make the server as read-only without CLI and through Node.js code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ftp.on('login', (data, resolve, reject) => {
    return resolve({
        blacklist: ['ALLO', 'APPE', 'DELE', 'MKD', 'RMD', 'RNRF', 'RNTO', 'STOR', 'STRU'],
    });
});
```